# Deserialize XML Response String to C# Class

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I know there has been a good amount of posts on this, though I find this topic of .NET very difficult to comprehend. I have an XML string that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result command="searchhotels" tID="1460064669000001" ip="99.51.186.120"  date="2016-04-07 21:31:16" version="2.0" elapsedTime="7.1676669120789">
    <currencyShort>USD</currencyShort>
    <hotels count="2">
        <hotel runno="0" preferred="no" cityname="DUBAI" order="3" hotelid="275975">
            <from>292.767
                <formatted>292.77</formatted>
            </from>
            <availability>available</availability>
        </hotel>
        <hotel runno="1" preferred="yes" cityname="DUBAI" order="3" hotelid="31084">
            <from>278.7142
                <formatted>278.71</formatted>
            </from>
            <availability>available</availability>
        </hotel>
    </hotels>
    <successful>TRUE</successful>
</result>
```

I want to map this to a class, based on the documentation and posts that I've read I have no idea how to do this or what the class should look like. Help? Here is what I have so far....

"response" is the xml string...
turning string into class:

```
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TResponse));
        using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(response))
        {

            TResponse deserialized = (TResponse)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            return deserialized;
        }
```

I do not know what the class should look like, I've tried turning that response into a C# class using online tools but nothing seems to work. So what should the class for this response look like? And how can I turn the string into this class?

Comment: You can either use xsd or some tools like http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: nice that worked for the class

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at xsd.exe - google it - it is a little utility that you can use to generate .net class structures based on xml (it will infer structure) or xsd files.

With it you can generate a class that you can populate in your deserialization code.

Comment: It is packaged with your .Net framework so it will be something like C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6 Tools\

Comment: nice, any thoughts on the string deserialization? does it look right above

Comment: It looks fine to me.  If your class is structured properly it should go in.  Throw a try / catch around it just in case.  One bit to look out for - I have noticed that occasionally some of the utilities will generate enums with upper and lowercase values eg. Y, y, N,n.  In that case just manually remove either the upper or lower case entry.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to generate classes to deserialize your XML, you can try this online tool, [Xml2CSharp](http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/). That shortcut might work.

Otherwise you'll need to generate a schema from your XML and then generate classes from the schema. [This article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/yojoshi/2011/05/14/auto-generating-entity-classes-with-xsd-exe-for-xml-serialization-and-de-serialization/) describes the steps clearly.